# Cannot connect to mysql database from popsql with my vscode

Tags: java, mysql, visual-studio-code, jdbc, popsql

**#java code for connection with jdbc**

import java.sql.*;
public class abc {

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
```

**# my driver which i am using**

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//kushagra";

    String user="root@localhost";

    String password="kushagra";
```

**#query written in popsql this a mysql query**

```
    String query = "Select student_name From students where student_id =1";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");



    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    rs.next();

    String name = rs.getString("student_name");

    System.out.println(name);

    st.close();
    con.close();



}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

user chanage to 'root'

```java
String user="root";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please confirm whether you have correctly imported the java connection database driver package in VS Code. You can click the plus sign after **Referenced Libraries** in **JAVA PROJECTS** to import.

[image]

In addition, `String user="root@localhost"` in the code can be modified to `String user="root"`.